# EF designer doesn't see provider

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have added some ADO.NET EF provider to App.config of project with model (through DbProviderFactories section) and referenced appropriate assembly but EF designer says "Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid". What may be the reasons for that? Does EF designer impose any specific restrictions to providers?

Comment: I'm almost sure that EF Designer doesn't read providers from configuration file - to have provider available in  EF designer you must "install" it. Not every provider is available for EF designer and not every provider is available for EF.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, that's strange as designer reads connection strings from local App.config

Comment: Yes it does but the provider selection wizard is not related to your config - even not every installed provider in machine.config will not appear there because not every provider is enabled for EF.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, I guess you are right: provider should be "installed" in Machine.config and registered in GAC. Unfortunately I couldn't find any specific information about it. Please post your comments as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments I'm almost sure that EF Designer doesn't read providers from configuration file - to have provider available in EF designer you must "install" it and even that is not enough (for example SQL CE 4 is available for EF but it is not available in provider selection in EF designer). Not every provider is available for EF designer and not every provider is available for EF (for example ODBC or OleDB providers are not enabled for EF).

Comment: Btw, SQL CE 4 provider is available to EF designer only from Web Application project (the strangest thing ever)